# Using a Java WatchService to monitor folders within folders

Tags: java, nio, nio2, watchservice

I'm trying out WatchService with Java 7, to monitor a folder. I want it to monitor any files or folders being added to the path registered with the WatchService.

If I add a folder to the registered path it detects it correctly as ENTRY_CREATE and returns the name of the folder in watchEvent.context(). But if I add a folder to that folder than again it is detected but watchEvent.context() returns the same folder and ENTRY_MODIFY, because that folder has been modified by adding another folder.

So I understand this but don't know if I should be registering every folder within the structure and or just registering the top folder and listening or CREATE and MODIFY

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java should be useful, it shows how to add WatchKeys recursively by walking the FileTree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct support for that across platforms. For Windows there is an `ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE` that will watch a directory recursively. However there is no equivalent functionality on Mac or Linux. Also, note that `ExtendedWatchEventModifier` is an extension and not part of the standard definition.

You have to listen for CREATE and DELETE. When the object created (deleted) is a directory you need to add (remove) a new watch on the subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks, you mean this http://jpathwatch.sourceforge.net/ . Looks like it may support OSX now buts seems a safer bet for me to just register every folder

Comment: I believe that is where much of the WatchService concepts originated. but it is part of OpenJDK7 as well: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/nio/file/ExtendedWatchEventModifier.java.html
Note that this is a com.sun.* class.

Comment: I found ExtendedWatchEventModifier in the jdk.unsupported library at least since Java 10.